Is it possible to seed data as part of docker compose up -d
I have the following docker-compose.yml file:
version: "3.7"

services:
  dc-patients:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      labels:
        service: "patients"
    image: hubaccount/patients:latest
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    env_file:
      - ./variables.env
    depends_on:
      - dc-patients-db
  dc-patients-db:
    image: postgres:16.2
    ports:
      - "8005:5432"
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - ./variables.env

volumes:
  data-volume:

When I run docker compose up -d this runs fine. My API in the dc-patients container runs fine and so does my database container.
The issue is, the database is empty and because I'm in the development phase, I want some test data in my patients table (e.g. 100 records). Right now I have to manually connect to the database and manually seed some test data in there.
Is it possible to have docker compose up -d run the container but also seed the patients table in the Postgres container with a 100 records (I can get a CSV file that has the test data).
And have docker compose down clear the data.
This way I can schedule a corn job on my VPS to run docker compose down followed by docker compose up -d every night so that my env always resets and I have data to work with?
I'm not really sure if such a thing is even doable, but I thought I'd ask!

Have a psql script run to load the database at startup:
  dc-patients-db:
    image: postgres:16.2
    ports:
      - "8005:5432"
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./seed.sql:/tmp/seed.sql:rw
    command: sh -c "psql -p 5432 postgres < /tmp/seed.sql"
    env_file:
      - ./variables.env

So it does not keep reloading the same data, you might want seed.sql to include steps to drop the existing database then re-create it.

I don't know what I'm missing, but I'm getting the following error: ~/code/dc/patients main* ❯ docker logs d97 psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory         Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
It is like it can't connect to psql inside the container!

@J86 maybe environment variables need to be set? I see the variables.env--does that include settings for POSTGRES_USER and POSTGRES_PASSWORD? You might need to log into the container and find out what exactly is happening. Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645550/postgresql-why-psql-cant-connect-to-server
